# Class for AVL trees (C++)

Tags: c++, tree, nodes, avl-tree

So I wanted to make an AVL tree in C++. I used a class to make the nodes and a class for the rest of the fuctions (instert, delete etc). When I want to make more than one tree I decided that I needed to make more roots (one for every tree). The problem is when I declare the new root inside `main`. When I declare it outside it seems to work fine.

avlNode:

```
class avl_node
{
public:
    int data;
    avl_node *left;
    avl_node *right;
}*root;
```

avlTree::insert implementation:

```
avl_node* avlTree::insert(avl_node* root, int item)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new avl_node;
        root->data = item;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    if (item < root->data) {
        root->left = insert(root->left, item);
    }
    else if (item > root->data) {
        root->right = insert(root->right, item);
    }
    else if (item == root->data) {
        cout << "this exists" << endl;
    }
    root = balance(root);
    return root;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    avl_node* roott;
    int item;   
    avlTree avl;
    avlTree kk;               
    root = avl.insert(root, item);          
    roott = kk.insert(roott, item);
    kk.display(roott, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Jenny I can't spot any memory allocation for any of those `avl_node*` pointers.

Comment: when i writte this

   avl_node *roott;
in the main the programm stops working but when i write it outside it works fine

Comment: @Jenny That's probably because you have undefined behavior elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Post the implementation of `avlTree::insert`.

Comment: so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// in main
root = avl.insert(root, item);

// in avlTree::insert
avl_node* avlTree::insert(avl_node* root, int item) {
    if (root == NULL) { // <- Here
```

At `Here`, you are using `::root` which is not initialized. At this point, `::root` points to some random address, which is not what you want.

Write

```
}*root = NULL;
```

and

```
avl_node* roott = NULL;
```

to initialize those pointers.
You also need to initialize the `int item` in your `main`, presumably to `0`.

```
int item = 0;
```

Comment: Yes this seems to fix it.Thank you.